# Qt - Detect item information change in QListView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListView which is connected to a QStandardItemModel. How do I detect any information change in the model or the QListView? I tried the Signals and Slots with the itemChanged() for the model but it seems to crash the whole program.

```
Qbject::connect(bugModel, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), this, SLOT(bugInfoChanged()));
```

That is the code I'm using to connect the Signal. the function bugInfoChanged() just runs a qDebug() that says "Changed". But when I start the program, it shows a crash error.

Comment: Do you want to update the model, when user changes data, or update view, when model gets changed, or what?

Comment: Maybe post some more code that shows where you are using the `itemChanged` signal. That is the correct signal to register; there must be something else wrong.

Comment: I want to save some infos in QSettings when the user changes the informations in that model, which will automatically get updated if a change is made in the list.

Comment: Why are you sure, your crash conjuncted to this connection? Code, _you showed_, can _never_ cause crash. Your slot code produce crash or smth completely different.

Comment: -Comment given to answer- (i cant figure out how to show the code in a proper way)

Answer (score 0):

When I comment this line (//QObj...) then the crash doesn't occur, but again when I remove the comment it does crash. I have this in my "Private Slots" area:

```
    void bugInfoChanged();
```

and it's like this in the cpp:

```
    void MainWindow::bugInfoChanged()
    {
       qDebug() << "Changed";
    }
```

I have no clue as to what causes the crash :/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Turns out if I place the connecting code in a function where the list is populated, it works just fine. It used to crash because the list didn't have any item at the moment when the App started.